# running windows on linux HOW TO?

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualization, fedora, emulation

I've got linux and windows while I use linux majority of my time. However from time to time I'd like to play some games which wine doesn't support without rebooting the machine. Is it possible to run windows inside the linux? Do I need to use emulator or is there another way without using wine?

Comment: Are you too lazy to reboot?

Comment: Wine is crap with .NET Just my $.02

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can but you would need a virtual machine that runs on your linux machine, once installed add and install windows onto it, You should be able to play any windows game ;)

https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: Just bear in mind that any resource intensive games will run slower on the virtual machine than they do when you reboot into windows. The VM will not have access to all your CPU/RAM since you still need to run your linux system at the same time.

Comment: Yup you are right! except if you have a very good pc or laptop with say 6GB+ ram and i5+ cpu with no less than 1GB+ dedicated graphics card then it should be fine sharing the ram and cpu :).

Comment: It's actually more complicated than that. Resource intensive games often require an actual graphics card, not the virtualized one you get in a typical VM. Yes, you can have 2 on the host and use a very complicated passtrough configuration to use one directly in the guest. Then and ONLY then the more or less cores and RAM come into play.

Answer (score 0):

For gaming, the simple answer is: Don't do it. While virtualisation and virtual machines are great technologies, the performance of almost all modern games that require 3D rendering is massively reduced.

Tier 2 hypervisors, like the ones for example Virtualbox uses, usually don't support dedicated graphics cards natively, which is a huge issue for gaming.

You will waste a lot of your machines potential, becuase it has to share its recources and keep the VM alive.

Just reboot and enjoy full performance and stability in game.